# Why doesn't Oracle SQL allow us to use column aliases in GROUP BY clauses?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, alias

This is a situation I'm generally facing while writing SQL queries. I think that writing the whole column (e.g. long case expressions, sum functions with long parameters) instead of aliases in GROUP BY expressions makes the query longer and less readable. Why doesn't Oracle SQL allow us to use the column aliases in GROUP BY clause? There must be an important reason behind it.

Comment: Of course, in Oracle you can, using a subquery - e.g. `SELECT g, SUM(n) FROM (SELECT my-complicated-expression AS g, n FROM bla) GROUP BY g` :)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp. You should post this as an answer. If the "No you can't" answer can gather 21 upvotes (at the time of writing) a "Yes you can" one is worth much more!

Comment: My comment doesn't strictly answer the question, it's really just a workaround.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It isn't just Oracle SQL, in fact I believe it is conforming to the ANSI SQL standard (though I don't have a reference for that).  The reason is that the SELECT clause is logically processed **after** the GROUP BY clause, so at the time the GROUP BY is done the aliases don't yet exist.

Perhaps this somewhat ridiculous example helps clarify the issue and the ambiguity that SQL is avoiding:

```
SQL> select job as sal, sum(sal) as job
  2  from scott.emp
  3  group by job;

SAL              JOB
--------- ----------
ANALYST         6000
CLERK           4150
MANAGER         8275
PRESIDENT       5000
SALESMAN        5600
```

Comment: Thank you also and +1 for the nice example.

Answer (score 16):

I know this is an old thread, but it seems the users problem wasn't really solved; the explanations were good in explaining why the group by clause doesn't let you use aliases, but no alternative was given.

Based on the info above, the aliases can't be used in the group by since group by runs first, before aliases from the select clause are stored in memory.  So the simple solution which worked for my view was to add an outer select which simply selects the aliases, and then groups at that same level.

Example:

```
SELECT alias1, alias2, alias3, aliasN
FROM
(SELECT field1 as alias1, field2 as alias2, field3 as alias3, fieldN as aliasN
 FROM tableName
 WHERE ' ' = ' ')
GROUP BY alias1, alias2, alias3, aliasN
```

Pretty straight forward once you see the solution, but a PITA if trying to figure out by yourself for first time.

This is the only way I have been able to "group by" for a derived field from a case statement, so this is a good trick to know.

Comment: Whilst this may be a "solution" it does ask the DB to do extra work for no reason. In this case type the extra few characters... that's why you're being employed after all.

Comment: @Ben, it doesn't cause any more work necessarily. Oracle has been able to roll subqueries into the main query for a long time. There's rarely any need to repeat yourself in a query.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree it would be helpful to reference expressions with aliases in the GROUP BY clause, my guess is that it is not possible because the GROUP BY clause is evaluated **before** the SELECT clause.

This would also explain why you can use column aliases in the ORDER BY clause (i-e: the ORDER BY clause is evaluated last).

Comment: So it would seem the correct question should be "why can't we define aliases in the group-by clause, and reuse them in the select clause?".

Comment: @nadavwr 1) not all queries have GROUP BY, 2) Not all columns are GROUPed BY. The SELECT clause is the most logical place to define aliases, this is why it has been defined there in the SQL standard. Furthermore, not being able to define aliases in the group by is a minor inconvenience, you can use subqueries easily if you don't want to type :)

Answer (score 3):

While it seems a logical answer, in fact it's a very user-unfriendly one.
Prior to processing the query Oracle reads it, and by reading it the preprocessor can replace the alias by the original statement and still send the correct query to the database.
same as you can code order by 1,2,3, you should also be able to group by 1,2,3 or alias.

Answer (score 2):

But some RDBMS do, this works on PostgreSQL:

```
select emp.lastname || ' ' || emp.firstname as fullname, count(emp_work.*) as cnt
from emp
left join emp_work using(emp_id)
group by fullname
```

That will work, as long as the grouped alias is not the result of aggregate functions, `group by cnt` will not work

But I can hazard a guess that `group by fullname` gets expanded to `group by emp.lastname || ' ' || emp.firstname as fullname`, and the SELECT clause just pick the fullname result from that grouping; though syntactically it looks the other way around.  GROUP always executes first, then projections last(i.e. SELECT)

Comment: Good old FoxPro (and I believe dBase, though that is a little too long ago) also supported alias group by. I was pretty surprised to find out later that something so basic doesn't work on major DBMS like Oracle. As someone already pointed out, even though group by is evaluated first, why not let a preprocessor deal with this?