# Adding up the rows of a column in a query

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT sac.cred, s.status, (SELECT NVL (csl.census_dates, tl.census_dates) 
                                         FROM  schema.sections cs,  schema.sections_ls csl,  schema.terms tl 
                                        WHERE cs.course_sections_id = csl.course_sections_id(+)AND csl.pos(+) = 1 AND cs.term = tl.terms_id 
                                          AND tl.pos = 1 AND cs.course_sections_id = cs2.course_sections_id AND ROWNUM = 1)AS censusDate, 
                                      (SELECT NVL (p.ssn, 'xxx-xx-xxxx') FROM   schema.person p 
                                        WHERE p.id = sac.person_id) AS ssn, 
                                       //schema.person_name(sac.person_id, 'FML') as fml, 
                                       //schema.person_name(sac.person_id, 'LF') as lf 
                                 FROM  schema.student_acad_cred sac JOIN  schema.statuses s 
                                   ON s.student_acad_cred_id = sac.student_acad_cred_id 
                                 JOIN  schema.terms tl ON sac.term = tl.terms_id 
                                 JOIN  schema.student_course_sec scs ON sac.student_course_sec = scs.student_course_sec_id 
                                 JOIN  schema.course_sections cs2 ON scs.course_section = cs2.course_sections_id 
                                 JOIN  schema.terms t ON tl.terms_id = t.terms_id 
                                WHERE sac.person_id = '1111111111' 
                                  AND (s.status IN ('A', 'N') OR (s.status = 'D' AND final_grade IS NOT NULL)) 
                                  AND s.pos = '1'AND tl.pos = '1' AND tl.terms_id = 'spring';
```

And here are the results:

```
cred      status   currentDate   censusDate     ssn
====      ======   ===========   ==========     ===
  3         N       11/16/2011   12/15/2011      xxx-xx-xxxx
  4         N       11/16/2011   12/15/2011      xxx-xx-xxxx
  3         N       11/16/2011   12/15/2011      xxx-xx-xxxx
  4         N       11/16/2011   12/15/2011      xxx-xx-xxxx
  1         N       11/16/2011   12/15/2011      xxx-xx-xxxx
```

Okay, what I am trying to do is use sum() (or some other function) to add up all the credit hours that are pulled.  So in this instance the sum of all cred hours would be '15'.  Is there a way to do this in query?  Ideally I would want something like this:

```
cred      status   currentDate   censusDate     ssn
====      ======   ===========   ==========     ===
 15         N       11/16/2011   12/15/2011      xxx-xx-xxxx
```

Comment: Why would you want to show `SUM` credit information for individual records? Also, why would `ssn` ever be different for the same person when you're getting the `ssn` based on a non-changing `person_id`? In fact, why don't you just `JOIN` to `schema.person` instead of doing a sub-select?

Comment: Do I really need a reason? Lol, the sum of credit hours is, no doubt, needed.  The reults are just completely made up, I was just typing things.  Joining to person would take 3 more joins (I didnt set up the tables), and it makes the query take about twice as long to execute.

Comment: 3 more joins? It would take exactly one join: `JOIN schema.person p ON sac.person_id = p.person_id`. You're essentially doing it already, just in a very strange way. The reason I'm asking is because your output doesn't make any sense -- the `ssn` would never be different, it would always be the same. After we've established that fact, it's trivial to see that you're just outputting the same row 5 times... which is silly. Instead, you should be doing a `GROUP BY` and only producing one row, which is where a `SUM` makes sense.

Comment: Okay, I apologize, I misunderstood your previous comment, but you are right about the joins, I can take care of that no problem.   As far as the ssn goes, I was just throwing #'s out there, they will always be the exact same, and it is fixed now. I guess the part that I was asking about is using the sum and the group by to get one row.

Comment: Question edited, and thanks for the tips.

Comment: Got it! Now I understand the question. See answer below. (I don't have access to an Oracle box at the moment to test it, but I'm pretty confident about my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to `GROUP BY` all of your other columns. Since you [can't group by aliased columns directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681494/why-doesnt-oracle-sql-allow-us-to-use-column-aliases-in-group-by-clauses) (in Oracle and most RDMBSes), you have to wrap the whole thing in another query and do the grouping there.

```
SELECT SUM(cred), status, censusDate, ssn 
FROM
    (SELECT sac.cred, s.status, 
          (SELECT NVL (csl.census_dates, tl.census_dates) 
             FROM  schema.sections cs,  schema.sections_ls csl,  schema.terms tl 
            WHERE cs.course_sections_id = csl.course_sections_id(+)AND csl.pos(+) = 1 AND cs.term = tl.terms_id 
              AND tl.pos = 1 AND cs.course_sections_id = cs2.course_sections_id AND ROWNUM = 1)AS censusDate, 
          (SELECT NVL (p.ssn, 'xxx-xx-xxxx') FROM   schema.person p 
            WHERE p.id = sac.person_id) AS ssn, 
           //schema.person_name(sac.person_id, 'FML') as fml, 
           //schema.person_name(sac.person_id, 'LF') as lf 
     FROM  schema.student_acad_cred sac JOIN  schema.statuses s 
       ON s.student_acad_cred_id = sac.student_acad_cred_id 
     JOIN  schema.terms tl ON sac.term = tl.terms_id 
     JOIN  schema.student_course_sec scs ON sac.student_course_sec = scs.student_course_sec_id 
     JOIN  schema.course_sections cs2 ON scs.course_section = cs2.course_sections_id 
     JOIN  schema.terms t ON tl.terms_id = t.terms_id 
    WHERE sac.person_id = '1111111111' 
      AND (s.status IN ('A', 'N') OR (s.status = 'D' AND final_grade IS NOT NULL)) 
      AND s.pos = '1'AND tl.pos = '1' AND tl.terms_id = 'spring')
GROUP BY status, censusDate, ssn;
```

This looks ugly, but doesn't actually have a horrible performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

```
select groupcol, sum(cred)
from table1
group by rollup(groupcol)
```