# How to code long group by/case clauses in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Quite often I have queries in which I want to group by a case clause, like:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN FIELD IS NULL                     |
    AND (SOMETHING > 100 OR SOMETHINGELSE < 50) |
    AND THATDATE >= add_months(sysdate, -4)     | -> Case
        THEN 0 ELSE 1                           |                                                               
    END AS dim_1,                               |                                                               
    dim_2,
    sum(SOMEFIELD_TOTAL) as measure_1
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN FIELD IS NULL                     | 
    AND (SOMETHING > 100 OR SOMETHINGELSE < 50) | 
    AND THATDATE >= add_months(sysdate, -4)     | -> Same case
        THEN 0 ELSE 1                           |                                                                
    END,                                        |                                                                
    dim_2
```

Is there a way I could use the alias I defined for the whole case into the `group by`, like, `group by dim_1`?

Found [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681494/why-doesnt-oracle-sql-allow-us-to-use-column-aliases-in-group-by-clauses), still, I was wondering if there was way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`subquery factoring`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) also know as `named subquery` and  `common table expression (CTE)` (Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name)

```
WITH t as 
(
SELECT
    CASE WHEN FIELD IS NULL                     
    AND (SOMETHING > 100 OR SOMETHINGELSE < 50) 
    AND THATDATE >= add_months(sysdate, -4)     
        THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS dim_1,         
    dim_2,
    SOMEFIELD_TOTAL as measure_1
FROM MY_TABLE
)
SELECT dim_1, dim_2, sum(SOMEFIELD_TOTAL)
FROM t
GROUP BY dim_1, dim_2
```

The advantage of this method is that you can have many subqueries without having to join them as in a regular subquery (inner select)

Comment: As a side note: the "official" name (as per ANSI SQL standard) of this feature is "common table expression" (or CTE)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are getting overly concerned with repeating the expression. Oracle and any other DBMS will recognize the expression as a duplicate and calculate it only once.  If you simply don't wish to repeat it (it's just ***cut-and-paste*** triviality mind you), the you can use a derived table or common table expression.

```
SELECT 
    dim_1, dim_2, sum(SOMEFIELD_TOTAL) as measure_1
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN FIELD IS NULL                     |
        AND (SOMETHING > 100 OR SOMETHINGELSE < 50) |
        AND THATDATE >= add_months(sysdate, -4)     | -> Case
            THEN 0 ELSE 1                           |                                                               
        END AS dim_1,                               |                                                               
        dim_2,
        SOMEFIELD_TOTAL
    FROM MY_TABLE
) AS SQ
GROUP BY
    dim_1, dim_2
```

It doesn't really look much better, does it?

Comment: Well, generally I'd agreed to you. I was more concerned about the code, really. This example is quite simple, but some times I have *really* long `case`s and more than one in the same sentence. Although it all comes down to cut-and-paste as you say, when the code gets long, it is always a place for typos and silly mistakes. Anyway, the syntax you put might help in the future. Thanks.