# Error message / troubleshooting my code

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm getting the following error message when I run my query:

ORA-00904: "ACCNT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 33 Column: 29

Here is the code I'm running:

```
select 
pdl.business_unit as BU,
pdl.deptid as BR,
pb.in_service_dt as IN_SERVICE_DATE,
pdl.asset_id as ASSET_ID,
pa.descr as DESCRIPTION,
pa.serial_id as SERIAL_NUMBER,
pdl.account as ACCNT,

case when pdl.trans_in_out = 'I' then 'TRANSFERRED TO' else pdl.deptid end as DEPTID,

MAX(CASE WHEN (pdl.trans_in_out = 'O') then pdl.deptid END) as ACCT_FROM,
MAX(CASE WHEN (pdl.trans_in_out = 'I') then pdl.deptid END) as ACCT_TO

From ps_dist_ln pdl,
ps_book pb,
ps_asset pa

where 
pdl.business_unit = 'A0465'
and pdl.fiscal_year = '2014'
and pdl.asset_id = '000000000151'
and pdl.accounting_period = '12'
and pdl.trans_type = 'RCT'
and pdl.distribution_type = 'FA'
and pdl.book = 'PERFORM'
and pdl.asset_id = pb.asset_id and pdl.business_unit = pb.business_unit
and pdl.asset_id = pa.asset_id and pdl.business_unit = pa.business_unit

GROUP BY
BU,
BR,
IN_SERVICE_DATE,
ASSET_ID,
DESCRIPTION,
SERIAL_NUMBER,
ACCNT,
DEPTID
```

I can't figure out why I am getting this error.  All of the field names and aliases look correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank You for your help.

Comment: From here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082571/replace-query-results-for-a-field-with-a-string -- I answered, didn't notice Oracle tag.  I gave an answer for SQL-Server.  Not sure if Oracle supports "CASE" syntax.  Please be clear on RDBMS.  I removed SQL-Server tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GROUP BY does not recognize aliases defined in the SELECT clause.

If your SELECT statement says this:

```
SELECT
    pdl.business_unit as BU,
    pdl.deptid as BR,
    pb.in_service_dt as IN_SERVICE_DATE,
    pdl.asset_id as ASSET_ID,
    pa.descr as DESCRIPTION,
    pa.serial_id as SERIAL_NUMBER,
    pdl.account as ACCNT,
    case when pdl.trans_in_out = 'I' then 'TRANSFERRED TO' else pdl.deptid end AS DEPTID
```

Then your GROUP BY statement should say this:

```
GROUP BY 
    pdl.business_unit,
    pdl.deptid,
    pb.in_service_dt,
    pdl.asset_id,
    pa.descr,
    pa.serial_id,
    pdl.account,
    case when pdl.trans_in_out = 'I' then 'TRANSFERRED TO' else pdl.deptid end
```

Comment: Nice.  And for a good example on why the aliases don't work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2681576/429982

Comment: You're welcome, @Shaves. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.