# Oracle SQL division

Tags: sql, oracle

I have

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS a,
SUM(CASE WHEN r.hn IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS b,
SUM(CASE WHEN r.hn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c,
( ____ / ____ ) AS d
FROM
x
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT xn FROM yn) r ON x.xn = y.xn;
```

I need the blanks on line 4 to be the values set to 'a' and 'c', I'm not sure what the correct syntax is though.

Comment: You can simplify things some (and potentially speed up your query, too), by using the fact that `COUNT(<columnName>)` will **not** count nulls.

Answer (score 2):

You can't refer to column aliases in the same level of the query ([except in the `order by` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55280)), so you have to either repeat the original expression as in @juergend's answer, or use an inline view:

```
SELECT a, b, c, a/c AS d
FROM (
  SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS a,
  SUM(CASE WHEN y.hn IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS b,
  SUM(CASE WHEN y.hn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c
  FROM x
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT xn FROM yn) y ON y.xn = x.xn
);
```

For complicated expressions this is a bit simpler and easier to maintain - if the expression changes you only have to modify it in one place, reducing the risk of a mistake.

If you're trying to make `d` the ratio of nulls to the total then you just need the division reversed, as `c/a`; and if you wanted the percentage then`100*c/a`, possibly rounded or truncated to a certain precision.

And as Clockwork-Muse mentioned, since `count()` ignores nulls, you coudl use that instead of the two `sum()` calls:

```
SELECT a, b, c, a/c AS d
FROM (
  SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS a,
  COUNT(y.hn) AS b,
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(y.hn) AS c
  FROM x
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT xn FROM yn) y ON y.xn = x.xn
);
```

... or you could calculate `c` in the outer query too, as `(b - a)`, though that makes the `d` calculation messier.

Comment: @compscinoob - because of the order that the query is evaluated internally. The select list items are the last part - after joins, filters etc. - apart from ordering, so the aliases just don't exist yet to the parser. And also because you can reuse an actual column name as an alias, which would be ambigous, [like in this demo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2681576/266304).

Comment: @compscinoob - I have no idea why you changed the aliases and column names in your question,  but the principal is exactly the same, you still need to refer to the inner query's aliases in an outer query to do the amended calculation. I've included a couple of variations as it isn't entirely clear what you need to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is to rewrite the statements again. You can't re-use alias names in the `select` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS t,
       count(r.hn) AS c,
       SUM(case when r.hn IS NULL then 1 end) AS u,
       count(r.hn) / SUM(case when r.hn IS NULL then 1 end) AS p
FROM h
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT hn FROM r) r ON h.hn = r.hn;
```

Comment: Then you need the `case` in Oracle. I was not quite sure. I updated the answer